# Access component's properties from it's template

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a quick question I found hard to google.
Say I have a component's template that looks smth like this:

```
<div item
*ngFor="let item of items; let i = index;"
dnd-sortable
[dragEnabled]="true"></div>
```

dnd-draggable is a directive that allows dragging items. I want to set drag enabled to a property inside of the item component. So changes in the item component would determine if it is draggable or not.

I image this shouldn't be too difficult, like [dragEnabled]="this.allowDragBoolean"

Thanks!

Comment: What is `dragEnabled`? Is it an `@Input()` in `dnd-sortable`?

Comment: Yup, sorry for not clarifying.

Comment: Then it should work.